# SuperAgent + Node.js Connection Refused

Tags: node.js, superagent

I'm pretty new to Node.js so this is possibly an basic understanding issue, but I'm getting `ECONNREFUSED` from a superagent http request when I don't think I should be:

```
$ curl http://localhost:5000/
{"you": "looking good"}

$ node
> var request = require("superagent");
> var req = request.get("http://localhost:5000/").on('error', function (err) {
    console.log("There's an emergency is going on.", err)
  }).end(function (data) {
    console.log("All is well", data.body)
  });

There's an emergency is going on. { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

What assumption have I made that is breaking this? I'm actually writing isomorphic JavaScript and the exact same code making the http query on the *browser* works fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a firewall problem, but first run `ping localhost` from a terminal. You should see `localhost` has IP `127.0.0.1`. If it doesn't your `hosts` file is probably incorrect or not being loaded, and will need fixing.

If it's correct, try these one at a time then repeat the `curl` and `superagent` requests for comparison. If one step doesn't work, reverse it and move to the next:

1. disable any firewall (if this is the problem, you should add a rule for `node` rather than leaving the firewall disabled)
2. disable any anti-virus (again add permissions rather than permanently disabling)
3. `sudo setenforce 0` if you're on a *nix (undo with `sudo setenforce 1`)
4. curl and superagent will use different `user-agent` strings - do you have a proxy running? Run `curl http://localhost:5000/ -vvv` to see exactly what curl is doing

If these still don't work you could try a packet capture tool like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) to trace the HTTP request and see where it's refused.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I still can't figure out exactly why, but running on `0.0.0.0` and accessing through my external IP rather than loopback fixed it. It's not a firewall issue (Mac OS; all firewalls down), or an anti-virus thing, there is no SELinux and the user agent doesn't seem to have any effect. I'll put it down to the magic gnomes. Thanks again.